# PFObject Array Sort

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm using Parse and I have an array of PFObjects called "scorecardData". Each PFObject has a "score" property that is of type Int. I'm trying to sort my array by "score" but I'm getting the following error: "Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'AnyObject?' operands". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I also tried down casting the objectForKey("score") as! Int but its not letting me do this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
    var scorecardData = [PFObject]()

    scorecardData.sortInPlace({$0.objectForKey("score") < $1.objectForKey("score")})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `scorecardData` variable as Array of `PFObject`. Why are you trying access `PFObject` property using `objectForKey:` reserved? Anyway I am not parse expert. But if you declared your array as `[PFObject]` you can use:

```
scorecardData.sortInPlace({$0.score < $1.score})
```

But this won't work unless you subclass PFObject for a more native object-oriented class structure. If you do that remember also to specify:

```
var scorecardData = [YOUR_NEW_CLASS]()
```

I strongly recommend subclassing PFObject to make use of all swift type-safe goodies.

But if you want to keep your data structure you can use:

```
scorecardData.sortInPlace({($0["score"] as! Int) < ($1["score"] as! Int)})
```

Keep in mind that it's dangerous, and in future avoid it.

Comment: Thanks zuziaka! Your solution worked. I'm still new at programming and will look into subclassing PFObject for this project to make my code better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Sort your array of PFOject... You can do this

```
extension Array where Element:PFObject {
    func sort() -> [PFObject] {
        return sort { (first, second) -> Bool in
            let firstDate   = first.objectForKey("time") as! NSDate//objectForKey(Constants.Parse.Fields.User.fullName) as? String
            let secondDate  = second.objectForKey("time") as! NSDate//objectForKey(Constants.Parse.Fields.User.fullName) as? String
            return firstDate.compare(secondDate) == .OrderedAscending
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"ScoreCard")

    // Sorts the results in ascending order by the score field
query.orderByDescending("score")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```